# How to get orginal size(link) images using in gallery wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating slider in pure JS. My Slider have 2 main elements. 
1. List of miniature images (gallery wordpress);
2. Div element. When When we click on miniature, then We see bigger picture.

It's working. But I have a problem. Quality picture is very poor. The result of this is reference src to miniature. How to get links from the database used by the gallery of the post?

I used get_the_post_gallery().

Comment: You can use `wp_get_attachment_image($id, $size="full")` function refer -- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

Answer (score 0):

```
$images = get_post_gallery( $post, false );
$ids = explode( ",", $images['ids'] );

foreach( $ids as $id ) {
   $link = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
// Now you can do something here to pass the URL to your js
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery
This is a way to fetch the URL's to the full size images. I didn't test the code but it should be good. Let me know if you have issues with it. I would provide a way to pass the URL to your JS but you didn't provide any code so it's hard.

Comment: Tommorow I check out.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its works :).
I litle modify code like this:

```
if (get_post_gallery()){
     initSliderAPI();
     $gallery = get_post_gallery( $post, false );
      $ids = explode( ",", $gallery['ids'] );
      $linkList = Array();
      $counter = 0;
      foreach( $ids as $id ) {
      $link = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
      $linkList[$counter] = $link;
      $counter++;
    }
```

I get links in nodeList "

" images, when API started, method createEvents create event to each node. Next When I got eventTarget <-- current node. API running. I checking firstChildElement in node (node(parent)-- images(children), and getting firstChildElement to field this.node and this.nodeID, then starting showImg (). showImg create Object Img and set link.

```
let node = this.domImageSliderGroup.item(this.nodeID);
  let image = new Image (300);
  image.src = node.firstChild.src;
```